# reason for not taking input of x in the loop in the test case, showing "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5 4 2 1' "

Tags: python, arrays

I am inserting values in an array but the x = int(input()) is showing eithr EOF error or invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5 4 2 1'

```
arr = array('i',[])
n = int(input("enter the length of array"))
print(n)

for i in range(n):
    x = int(input())
    arr.append(x)
```

Comment: you have to split first or use mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Given the error message, you are entering all the numbers on one single line, separated by spaces, then hitting the 'enter' key, so `input()` returns the string `"5 4 2 1"`, which is indeed not a valid representation of an integer.

Given how your code is written, the simple solution is to just enter *one* value, hit the 'enter' key, enter the second value, hit the 'enter' key, lather, rinse, repeat... You can make this expectation clearer by passing a prompt string to `input()`, ie:

```
for i in range(n):
    x = int(input("enter value #{} and hit enter".format(i+1)))
    arr.append(x)
```

Now if you expect your code to be reasonably robust, you want to properly handle wrong user inputs:

```
def get_integer_input(prompt):
    while True:
        value = input(prompt).strip()
        try:
            return int(value)
        except ValueError:
            print("sorry, '{}' is not a valid integer".format(value))
```

and then in your code snippet replace all the `int(input(...))` calls by a call to this function.

Answer (score -1):

```
arr=list(map(int,input().split()))
```

you will get array like this

```
import array as arr
arr = arr.array('i',[])
n = int(input("enter the length of array"))
print(n)
listt=(list(map(int,input().split())))
for i in listt:
    arr.append(i)
print(arr)
```

input.split() will convert '5 6 7 8' to ['5','6','7','8'] and mapping to int will convert it to [5,6,7,8]

Comment: This is probably closer to what the OP wants than the competing answer, but you really should add an explanation to unpack it for people who are new to Python.